# Jacoco code coverage for abstract class partly shows up

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, jacoco, test-coverage

I have an abstract class, lets say `MyClassA`, and a class that extends it, say `MyClassB`.
I have covered a method in `MyClassA` (not abstract) with unit tests, run them, everything's green.
Then after I run code coverage, I see that the only covered part that's shown is the constructor of `MyClassA`, which is strange, because it is created in `@Before` section of the test class.

The `@Before` section of `MyClassBUnitTests` looks something like this:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
   Context applicationContext = mock(Context.class);
   MemberModifier.stub(MemberMatcher.method(MyClassB.class,
                    "someFunction")).toReturn(null);
   classBInstance = new MyClassB(applicationContext, ...); 
   //calls the constructor of MyClassA through super()
}
```

The `@Test` section looks something like:

```
 @Test
 public void someTest() throws Exception {
    classBInstance = spy(classBInstance);
    MemberModifier.field(MyClassB.class, "somefield").set(classBInstance, someFieldStub);
    classBInstance.methodToTest();
    // actually calls a method implemented in MyClassA
}
```

And yes, I tried calling all stubs and modifiers on `MyClassA`, same.

Comment: what exactly is "strange" about this?

Comment: The fact that code coverage doesn't show a covered method, but shows the initialization

Comment: since your method runs the MyClassB, what else from MyClassA do you expect to be covered? remember that since you're not showing your MyClassA and MyClassB code, we don't really know that much about them

Comment: As I've said, MyClassB extends MyClassA

Comment: ... yah. do you overwrite the methods, only add others, ... and, yes, that might have an impact

Comment: No, Im testing a method which is in class A and it is not overriden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out I had to use

```
@Rule public PowerMockRule mPowerMockRule = new PowerMockRule();
```

inside of the test class instead of

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
```

annotation. Can't tell why though.

P. S. If you're using the first one - pay attention that the tests won't debug.